# Embeded PDF is rendered blank in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, rendering

I'm building a simple PDF viewer component in a Vue application and wanted to keep it as simple as possible just using the browser's built-in PDF viewer without relying on external libraries. The code that shows the PDF is something like this:

```
...
 <embed
   :src="pdfResource"
   type="application/pdf"
   width="500px"
   height="500px"
    >
...
```

Where pdfResource is the base64 string for the PDF which is obtained dynamically from a web service as these files are private.

The **problem** is that some PDFs are not rendered properly showing just a blank without any  PDF viewer loading in Chrome 86 and Safari 14, but is rendered properly in Firefox 81. I made a JSfiddle reproducing the issue with a random PDF found online

https://jsfiddle.net/26vLc3u0/2/

I tried using object and iframe tags  without any luck and I would like to avoid having to use external libraries. Note that I don't want to open the PDF on a new tab or generate a link to download it, the PDF must be rendered in full inside the component

thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see the pdf OK in Safari 13 and Chrome85 on IOS, is it just the more recent versions that are causing the problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I'm able to see the PDFs on Safari 14 and  Chrome 86 on  iOS 14, but their desktop versions (on Windows and macOS) aren't showing anything. Tried  on Chrome 84 in Windows 10  and it didn't work either

Comment: Now tested on Windows10 - Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and (even!) IE11 and all show the pdf OK - though some are reluctant to scroll through it on the jsfiddle they all will if I use local code. Sorry not to be of much help. Could there be something in the Adobe reader on your Windows m/c (I don't know how browsers access it, or whether they actually do).

Comment: Have the same problem with Chrome 99.0.4844.83